# Resharper shows an error from IO Stream in MVC Core, but I don't understand

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to read the body of a HTTP Request into a StreamReader in an MVC project.

I get this strange error and it's more than I know about .NET to solve it.
[image]

here's the detail from my CSPROJ:

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NReco.Data" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Comment: Please include the text of your .csproj in your question as a edit. However, if you have `<Content ... >` items you can just snip all them out to shorten the text in the question

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of ReSharper available? Some older versions are know for it having issues with .NET Core applications/projects. Try disabling Resharper and see if the error still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran in to this bug yesterday after adding the comment to the question. The error is caused by a bug in resharper, you should still be able to build and run the solution still.

Make sure you are running the latest version of resharper and have cleared your cache for resharper too. If the problem still persists submit a bug report to JetBrains.